# Backbone model validation

Tags: javascript, validation, model, backbone.js

I have encountered a strange behaviour of the model validation in Backbone.js.

When a model is first created, like

```
var foo = new Foo({
    bar: 42
});
```

Backbone invokes `foo.set()` passing as a parameter the given map `{bar: 42}`, as one can see from the [source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html). In doing so, it also passes the options `{silent: true}`, as in the line

```
this.set(attributes, {silent : true});
```

This makes sense, since having `silent === true` avoids triggering the `change` events, which do not make sense in this context.

For some reason I cannot understand, though, `silent === true` also **prevents validation**; see the source at the line

```
if (!options.silent && this.validate && !this._performValidation(attrs, options)) return false;
```

So it appears model are **never** validated when they are created, but they usually are when some attributes are changed. Moreover, the presence of the validation is inextricably tied to the action of sending `change` events, which is something completely orthogonal.

> Can anyone explain why this is so? What would be a clean and future proof way to fix this issue?

I could manually call `_performValidation`, but this has two drawbacks:

- first, it is something I could simply forget
- second,  `_performValidation` is not part of the API and maybe it will change in future releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I think that's a bug on Backbone.JS.

There is an open issue on GitHub here: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/870

**Edit :** In the new version 0.9.1 of Backbone.js, you can test if the model is valid with `isValid` method ( http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isValid )

Comment: Version 0.9.9 update:
Validation now occurs even during "silent" changes. This change means that the isValid method has been removed. Failed validations also trigger an error, even if an error callback is specified in the options.

Answer (score 0):

as of now the only way to stay safe is to never pass in parameters hash.

I always do:

```
var m = new MyModel();
// and then I do all the sets
m.set(...);
m.set(...);
m.set(...);
```

In case some JSON data comes from the DB, then they are supposed to have been validated already and so in that case it's fine to:

```
var m = MyMOdel(hashFromDB);
```

Does that make sense?